# mlocate not returning any results for known file, even after updatedb

Tags: locate

I am speechless...

```
[root@Centos-PHP56 webroot]# ls -al php_errors.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 327 Apr 21 01:49 php_errors.log
[root@Centos-PHP56 webroot]# updatedb
[root@Centos-PHP56 webroot]# locate php_errors.log
[root@Centos-PHP56 webroot]#
```

Am I just not using this correctly? Seems pretty straight forward to me...

Comment: If any directory along the path to your php_error.log is not world-readable, then the contents won't be found. Try `mlocate passwd`.

Comment: def finds some passwd files, for giggles I went ahead and chmod 777 everything from / to and including the file, did updatedb, and still nothing... Is this to be expected, even with 777 all the way to and including the file?

Comment: Have you looked at the various "prune" options in `/etc/updatedb.conf` to see if any apply to your file?